# MessageBodyMember Name Option Doesn't Set Correct Element Name in XML

Tags: c#, .net, wcf, web-services

I've got the following code in a WCF web service:

```
[MessageBodyMember(Order = 1, Name = "XmlInvoice")]
public new XElement XmlDocument { get; set; }
```

This WCF service runs successfully but the XML response contains the element `<XmlDocument>`, not `<XmlInvoice>`. How can I get this property to return as the element `<XmlInvoice>`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem with this code was inheritance. I was inheriting the XmlDocument property from a base class (not shown in the original post). In the base class, I had included the `MessageBodyMember` attribute and this was overriding the attribute in my sub class. I have updated my code so that the base class property definition does not include the `MessageBodyMember` attribute. Then, in the sub-class, I use the `MessageBodyMemeber` attribute with the `Name` parameter and the resulting XML contains the correct element name.